# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my form with the method PUT but instead it gives me an error

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

```
<form action="{{ route('accounts.update', $user->id) }}" method="put" role="form" name="_method">
     @csrf
     @method('PUT')

     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="balance" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Enter Client\'s Balance  :') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="balance" type="text" class="form-control @error('balance') is-invalid @enderror" name="balance" value=""  autocomplete="balance" autofocus>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="amount" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Enter Client\'s Amount:') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="amount" type="text" class="form-control @error('amt') is-invalid @enderror" name="amt" value="" required autocomplete="amt" autofocus>
        </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.card-body -->

     <div class="card-footer text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Account</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

and this is the route file

```
Route::get('/accounts/{id}/edit', 'AccountsController@edit')->name('accounts.edit');
Route::put('/accounts/{id}', 'AccountsController@update')->name('accounts.update');
```

Comment: Whats the difference between edit/update?

Comment: edit is where the form view is while update perform the function that update the account

Comment: I assume it's calling the other method.

Comment: this is the method for the update; ```public function update(StoreAccountsRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        
        $user->Accounts()->update($request->except('_method', '_token'));
        return redirect()->route('accounts.index')->with(['message' => 'Accounts updated successfully']);
    }```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<form action="{{ route('accounts.update', $user->id) }}" method="post">
              @csrf
              @method('PUT')

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="balance" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Enter Client\'s Balance  :') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="balance" type="text" class="form-control @error('balance') is-invalid @enderror" name="balance" value=""  autocomplete="balance" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="amount" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Enter Client\'s Amount:') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="amount" type="text" class="form-control @error('amt') is-invalid @enderror" name="amt" value="
                            " required autocomplete="amt" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->

                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Account</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Perhaps add a comment as to how your solution works. This might help future users of SO to understand your answer better and will give you likely more upvotes :-)

Comment: In form processing with the PUT method, you just need to define the post method on the form element

and use @method ('PUT') inside the form element

Comment: @AmadouBAH having issue updating table i'm using this controller ```public function update(StoreAccountsRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        
        Accounts::where('user_id','$user') -> update(['balance' => $request->balance, 'amt' => $request->amt]);

        return redirect()->route('accounts.index')->with(['message' => 'Accounts updated successfully']);
    }```

Comment: @TobyNwude use this code
 public function update(StoreAccountsRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        Accounts::where('user_id', $user->id)->update(['balance' => $request->balance, 'amt' => $request->amt]);
        return redirect()->route('accounts.index')->with(['message' => 'Accounts updated successfully']);
    }

replace 
Accounts::where('user_id','$user')
by this
Accounts::where('user_id', $user->id)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove **name="_method"** attribute from your **form** tag because it's reserved by laravel for hidden inputs

example :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"> // same as  @method('PUT')
```

see : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 0):

HTML form is not supporting PUT/PATCH method. So when you want to perform PUT/PATCH action using HTML form in Laravel, you have to add `@method('put')` and set form method as `method="post"`. So you can change your code as:

```
<form action="{{ route('accounts.update', $user->id) }}" method="post">
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')
   ....
</form>
```